Understanding the significance of an RSV-related paper
I was reading this paper on Nirsevimab, an RSV vaccine. The paper reports results from a clinical trial to determine the efficacy of the drug in preventing RSV infections in infants. The main finding is summarized in the figure below, where we see that the infection rates (after 150 days) between the treatment and placebo groups differ by roughly four percentage points, and the difference appear statistically significant.
Fine. So the drug does what it is designed to do. But then I looked at the y-axis and noticed that the two curves are both fairly close to 1: even the placebo group has a non-infection rate above 95%. A similar pattern (reported in the appendix of the paper) is true for the control group that received no intervention at all (i.e. no Nirsevimab or placebo).
This makes me wonder about the actual significance of the drug. That is, the drug only reduces the chance of catching RSV by a few percentage points from an already very safe level (~5% infection rate for the untreated). So, what's the point of taking the drug, or jab, to be precise?
I feel like I'm missing something important here, especially because the paper is published in the NEJM which is quite prestigious. I don't have a medical background, though I do have some training in statistics and experimental methods. I'd appreciate if someone can help me understand the actual significance of the finding.


Do the math. In the US, babies are ~3.3% of the population, which means ~11M babies. 4% of 11 million is 440K. Considering that RSV can be a severe, life-threatening illness in newborns, we can translate that number to NICU beds, but there are only about 35K NICU beds in the US. So I'd say 4% is more significant than it sounds.

The Y-axis isn't "infection", it is "medically attended RSV-associated lower respiratory tract infection".
"Medically attended" is important: for many mild RSV cases, they won't be even seen or diagnosed: just another cold. We're looking here at the cases serious enough to see a doctor.
From https://www.cdc.gov/han/2023/han00498.html

CDC estimates that every year RSV causes approximately 58,000–80,000 hospitalizations (1,2) and 100–300 deaths (3,4) in children ages <5 years

Most of these deaths and hospitalizations are infants, though the CDC doesn't specify exactly the proportions. If a vaccine reduces death and hospitalization by 75% similarly to the reduction in "medically attended" RSV (it could very likely be more effective for more severe outcomes, but more severe outcomes are also more difficult to study, you need a much larger sample size), that would mean saving 75-225 lives and 40-60,000 hospitalizations each year. That's a big win.

Thanks for the answer. Apparently "1% to 3% of children under 12 months of age in the United States are hospitalized each year due to RSV"

@HerrK. That sounds about right: about 3.5 million births, 2% would be about 70000 hospitalizations.

@HerrK. That's a Kaplan-Meier curve, AKA survival curve, though in this case the survival is "number of medically attended events", not "this patient is dead"
